# Select MySQL Group By

Tags: mysql

I have a table chat in mysql, it this the record of conversations between users.

The fields are.

id, id_from, id_to, message

```
Example (My Data in DB):

1, 50, 10, 'Hello'
2, 10, 50 'Nice?'
3, 50, 10, 'Yeah, And you?'
4, 10, 50, 'Me too'
5, 1, 20, 'Hello'
6, 20, 1, 'Nice?'
7, 1, 20, 'Yeah, And you?'
8, 20, 1, 'Me too'
8, 50, 1, 'Hey .....'
9, 1, 50, "Enhancements ??? '
10, 50, 1 ':)'
11, 1, 50, 'LOL'

[User]
id
name

id = Paul 50
id = 1 Samuel
id = Donald 20
id = 10 Max
```

What I need is via SELECT, return the last conversation that took place between people.

For example, in my select, I want to know the last two conversations (showing only the last message of each conversation) that id had 50 (Paul).

How Poderi do this via MySQL?

The result would be like this:

```
4, 10, 50, 'Me too'
11, 1, 50, 'LOL'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `id`s of the messages using:

```
select least(id_from, id_to), greatest(id_from, id_to), max(id)
from messages m
where 50 in (id_from, id_to)
group by least(id_from, id_to), greatest(id_from, id_to)
```

To get the messages, you can use `in` or `join`.  Here is one method:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.id in (select max(m2.id)
               from messages m2
               where 50 in (m2.id_from, m2.id_to)
               group by least(m2.id_from, m2.id_to), greatest(m2.id_from, m2.id_to)
              );
```

Comment: Show, thank you! :)) - Whats is the function least and greatest

Comment: I need to use the same SQL in SQLite too. But SQLite does not have least and greatest, as could replace?

Comment: @MilaSouza . . . You should ask another question if you want an answer about SQLite.  Databases are different, and the tags are important.